# Anyone know how to encode a video into bytes with 0 and 1 using ffmpeg and python

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, byte, encode

i am working on video encoding into bytes, im trying to find any solution on youtube but it doesnt have. Anyone know where to begin with.

Comment: You are going to need to give a lot more details than that to get any useful help. For a start, all digital video is bytes. What is your input, what do you want to create as your output, what have you tried already?

Comment: so i have a file .mp4 and i want to convert it into a text file that contain only 0 and 1. I have search for solution using ffmpeg but it dont have that converter

Comment: Do you mean "bits" when you say "bytes"? What would the 0s and 1s correspond to? Literally just the bits that make up the file or some result of processing the video? Processing it in what way? I can write a script that will take a video as input and write a series of random 1s and 0s to a file but I assume you want them to mean something specific?

Comment: Yes i mean i want to know what is the bits that show the begin and the end of the video. I'm doing the project about streaming a video